# highcharts column graph tooltip need to close when mouseout the cursor from the graph

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am having the Column Graph, while I'm hovering the cursor on graph tooltip is shown, but if i mouseout the cursor from the graph and placed the cursor inside the graph plot area then tooltip is not closed and it was showing the tooltip. I need to close the tooltip while i mouseout the cursor from the graph.
Note: this problem is facing when, i'm using the tooltip:{shared: true}
[image: Please refere image here]

Comment: Hi @Sandhya, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? As you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5y3ufosk/ tooltip works exactly as you want.

Comment: Hi, it was okay, but i need to use the tooltip: {shared: true}, at that time i'm facing the issue. Please refer here for Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw39jtu0/ to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `stickyTracking` property to `false` for series:

```
    series: [{
        stickyTracking: false,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1kg04jw5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stickyTracking